# Optimal program for saving time, hitting all muscles 2x a week + abs every workout

Tags: programs

My goal was to build a program that accomplishes a few goals:

- Hit all muscle groups twice a week (compounds + accessories)
- Utilize agonist antagonist supersets (staggered) in order to maximize gym efficiency + improve conditioning.
- Include core every workout.
- workouts under 50 minutes.

***Day 1 - Horizontal Push Pull***

**GROUP A**

- Barbell Bench Press - 3 sets x 8-12 reps
- Barbell Bent-Over Row - 3 sets x 8-12 reps

**GROUP B**

- Incline Dumbbell Bench Press- 3 sets x 8-12 reps
- Cable Row - 3 sets x 8-12 reps

**GROUP C**

- Barbell Calf Raise - 3 sets x 12-15 reps
- Hanging Leg Raise - 3 sets x 5-12 reps

**GROUP D**

- Romanian Deadlift - 3 sets x 8-12 reps
- Long Lever Plank - 3 sets x 60 seconds

***Day 2 - Vertical Push Pull***

**GROUP A**

- Weighted Pull Up - 3 sets x 6 reps
- Overhead Press - 3 sets x 6 reps

**GROUP B**

- Lat Pulldown - 3 sets x 8-12 reps
- Dumbbell shoulder press - 3 sets x 8-12 reps

**GROUP C**

- Hanging Leg Raise - 3 sets x 5-12 reps
- Dumbbell Side Raise - 3 sets x 12-15 reps

**GROUP D**

- MAchine Ab Crunch - 3 sets x 8-12 reps
- Dumbbell Front Raise - 3 sets x 12-15 reps

***Day 3 - Arms + Legs***

**GROUP A**

- Hanging Leg Raise - 3 sets x 5-12 reps
- Barbell Squat (heavy) - 3 sets x 5 reps

**GROUP B**

- Long Lever Plank - 3 sets x 60 seconds
- Barbell Deadlift - 3 sets x 5 reps

**GROUP C**

- EZ-Bar preacher curl - 3 sets x 10-12 reps
- French Press - 3 sets x 10-12 reps

**GROUP D**

- Hammer Curl - 3 sets x 8-12 reps
- Cable Pushdown - 3 sets x 10 - 12 reps

I'm assuming it's going to be pretty intense so I'll be lowering my weights a bit until conditioning improves. The goal is to balance out strength, conditioning, core, etc..

I put the leg accessories with the upper body compounds and the upper body accessories with the leg compounds. Gonna run this 3/6 days in a row with breaks after every 3 or after every 6 depending on fatigue.

Thoughts?

Comment: All looks nice, except this >Long Lever Plank. I'd recommened 1 set after some crunches/leg raises only, 3 is overdone

Answer (score 2):

Looks good. A few tweaks I’d recommend.

---

**Day #1:**

*Group C*

I would highly recommend removing dumbbell calf raises.  No need for isolation  gastroc/soleus training (due to fiber composition etc. you hit these else where in your workout and won’t notice much doing these alone). Instead I’d add in some kind of Plyo.

---

**Day #2:**

Ab crunch machine I would 100% ditch.  Any compound functional movement will hit your abs.  Aside from hitting your innercore (as a dynamic warm-up) stay far away from isolation ab training.

You’re hitting anterior delts twice (shoulder presses and front raises).  I’d add in some kind of D2 Flexion / Extension (Diagonal shoulder movements) using a med ball w/ lunges or battle ropes (X pattern).

---

**Day #3:**

Looks pretty solid, I’d keep it as is